# How to get an attribute/variable from a different class

Tags: java, class, netbeans, attributes

I'm programming in a class and I need to have a variable from a different class. How can I do this?

```
package domein;
public class Speler 
{
private String naam;
private String kleur;
private Sector sector;
private int Sector;
private int krediet = 10;
private int extraSchattingWaarde = 0;
private int nummer;


public Speler(String naam, String kleur, Sector sector)
{
    setNaam(naam);
    setKleur(kleur);
    setSector(sector);
}

public String getNaam()
{
    return this.naam;
}

public void setNaam(String naam)
{
    //controle of het leeg is??
    this.naam = naam;
}

public Sector getSector()
{
    return this.sector;
}

private void setSector(Sector sector)
{
    //tussen 1 en 4
    this.sector = sector;
}

public String getKleur()
{
    return this.kleur;
}

private void setKleur(String kleur)
{
    //controle of het de beschikbare kleuren zijn
    this.kleur = kleur;
}

public int getKrediet()
{
    return this.krediet;
}

public void setKrediet(int krediet)
{
    this.krediet = krediet;
}

public int getExtraSchattingWaarde()
{
    return this.extraSchattingWaarde;
}

public void setExtraSchattingWaarde(int waarde)
{
    this.extraSchattingWaarde = waarde;
}
```

}

This is the class where I need to get the variables and some methods. How can I make this class global?

Comment: use the `get____()` method of that class! You don't need to make the class global..just make those methods public!

Comment: Why don't you use the get methods to get the variables you need?

Comment: We work with the three layer model. I'm working in the ui, so we aren't allowed to do this: import domein.Speler

Comment: By setter and getter method , you can get and set  the values of objects.You need to call the methods by object name or by class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thing : this line is wrong `private int Sector;` because you can not use a class name as your variable name. This should hide your class visibility.
I assume this is an error and I continue the explanation.

In an other class you can instanciate this class and call the values. For example:

```
public class MyClass {

    private Speler mySpeler = new Speler("AAA", "BBB", 3);

    public MyClass() {}

    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println(mySpeler.getKleur());
      }
}
```